# Use Web3js library

Tags: web3js, wallets, javascript, nodejs

I am new to the use of blockchain we are building an application where I have the following problem to solve:

1. Users when registering in our system will create a wallet of an ethereum token
2. Be able to make internal transactions between all registered users

I have read about Web3js for the creation of wallets but I do not understand how this library works if you could give me some idea of ​​where to start.

Comment: The documetation seems clear. What did you try? and what didn't work?

Comment: I managed to create the wallets but I need to test what service or test network I can use where I can build my wallets and test the transactions

Comment: There are public testnets like rinkeby, kovan, ropsten, goerli, etc that anyone can use. It is also possible to use ganache a client for testing, or launch a private testnet with geth, openethereum.